# Java 11 - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, spring, java-11

I am working on a project which used the Jetty server. It uses a framework built on the top of Spring.
This project was running fine with Java 1.8. But when I changed Java version 11, the Jetty server stopped running.

I changed the Java version to 11 in properties tag in pom file

```
<javaVersion>11</javaVersion>
<jdk.path>C:/SomeFolder/I/T/jdk110_x64</jdk.path>
<jdk.javac>C:/SomeFolder/I/T/jdk110_x64/bin/javac.exe</jdk.javac>
```

But now, when I am trying to run the application, the following error is appearing on the console -

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\SomeFolder\al\al.jar;C:\Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\SomeFolder\al\al/jar;C:\Program
```

I also changed the Installed JREs path to JDK 11 in Eclipse -> preferences. But I am getting the above error.

Is it due to any version issue or any dependency version issue?

Comment: How are you running it and specifying the classpath? There are spaces in the path names and it looks like they are not being properly escaped.

Comment: @DavidConrad where are the spaces? I am running the application by right click -> Run as Java application on the JettyApp class. This way was working fine when I was using Java 8.  Specifying the classpath means?

Comment: There is a space in "Program Files".

Comment: @DavidConrad . That thing is appearing in the error. I havent set anything explicitly. And Program Files space was already there even using java 8

Comment: Our answers are based on the information given in the question. It is clearly recognizable from the error message that the command line has been messed up, as it reports a missing class named `Files\SomeFolder\al\al.jar;C:\Program` which is obviously supposed to be part of a path. Whether you have set anything explicitly, is irrelevant. Something has produced this broken command line. When you tried to run your application from Eclipse, its the launch configuration within Eclipse.

Comment: What can be the solution ? What should I try? @Holger

Comment: *Error: Could not find or load main class Files\SomeFolder\al\al.jar;C:\Program* That's doesn't look much to do with the Java version to me. It looks like part of some quite different area. One easy way to get around the horribly named Program Files is to use the DOS path `C:\PROGRA~1` You'd probably do well to post the whole of pom.xml

Comment: DOS path means? and how to do that? @g00se

Comment: It's the old FAT file system name, which even now is maintained in the file table to main compatibility. But there's no point in leaving us guessing as to what is happening. You're not giving enough information

Comment: Check what’s written in the [run configuration](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-java-local-configuration.htm)

Comment: I can't think of a good reason for the names of jars to be included in a path off C:\Program Files but that's what *appears* to be happening